# JNR-FFI - Callback Pointer crash

Tags: java, dll, jnr

I'm using the Win 32 library. I'm trying to call a callback with a pointer.
But when called, the function does not complete, but causes an error.

Example of DLL initialization:

```
Csclink csc = LibraryLoader.create(Csclink.class).option(LibraryOption.LoadNow, true)
                .search(libPath).convention(CallingConvention.STDCALL)
                .load("CscLink");
```

Example of Delegate block:

```
    public interface TEnumTransactions{
        @Delegate @StdCall
        void callback(int account, double date, Pointer pointer);
    }
```

And function

```
void GetAccountTransactions(int account, double firstDate, double SecondDate, TEnumTransactions transactions);

//Function call
csc.GetAccountTransactions(16972, 0, 0,(account1, date, pointer) -> {
  System.out.println(account1 + " " + date + " " + pointer);       
});
```

After callback i have next message `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Example implementation from C#

```
private delegate void EnumTransactionsCallback(int Account, DateTime RDate, ref TTransactionInfo info);

public static bool GetAllTransactions(DateTime DateFirst, DateTime DateLast, ref List<ETransactionInfo> listTransactions)
        {
            try
            {
                EnumTransactionsCallback callback = new EnumTransactionsCallback(AddTransaction);
                if (p_GetAllTransactions(DateFirst, DateLast, callback))
                {
                    LastMsg = "The request GetAllTransactions is successful";
                    listTransactions = ListTransactions;
                    return true;
                }
                LastMsg = GetError();
                flag = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LastMsg = e.ToString();
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

I tried to make a call as a structure, got an error, then I read in the documentation that it is better to call the structure through a pointer.
If you remove the pointer from the delegate, the function completes correctly.

Comment: Added this question to [git](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi/discussions/345)